# Time Complexity between Bubble and Insertion

Tags: c, sorting, time-complexity

I implemented 3 sorting logarithms in C: Bubble Sort, Insertion Sort, and Quick Sort. When I test the run time of the algorithms Insertion constant runs far faster than bubble sort. I was led to believe they should be around the same time by this link http://bigocheatsheet.com/
Can anyone explain why Insertion sort is so much faster?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void insertSort(int arr[], int size){
    int temp, j, i;

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++){
        temp = arr[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && temp < arr[j - 1]; j--){
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        }
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int first, int last){
    int pivot, j, temp, i;

    if (first < last){
        pivot = first;
        i = first;
        j = last;

        while (i < j){
            while (arr[i] <= arr[pivot] && i < last)
                i++;
            while (arr[j] > arr[pivot])
                j--;
            if (i < j){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        temp = arr[pivot];
        arr[pivot] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
        quicksort(arr, first, j - 1);
        quicksort(arr, j + 1, last);
    }
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int size){
    int x = 0, y;

    for (x; x < size; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < size - 1; y++){
            if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1]){
                int temp = arr[y + 1];
                arr[y + 1] = arr[y];
                arr[y] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int sizeArray){
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < sizeArray; i++){
        printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
    }

    //  printf("\n");
    //  for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
    //      printf("bubbleNums[%d] = %d     ", i, *(bubbleNums + i));
    //      printf("insertNums[%d] = %d     ", i, *(insertNums + i));
    //      printf("quickNums[%d] = %d\n", i, *(quickNums + i));
    //  }
}

int main(){
    int *bubbleNums = (int *)malloc(100000 * sizeof(int)), *quickNums = (int *)malloc(100000 * sizeof(int)), *insertNums = (int *)malloc(100000 * sizeof(int));
    int number;
    int randNumber;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf(" %i", &number);

    printf("\n");
    srand(100);
    for (i; i < number; i++){
        randNumber = rand() % 100;
        bubbleNums[i] = randNumber;
        insertNums[i] = randNumber;
        quickNums[i] = randNumber;
        //      printf("bubbleNums[%d] = %d     ", i, *(bubbleNums + i));
        //      printf("insertNums[%d] = %d     ", i, *(insertNums + i));
        //      printf("quickNums[%d] = %d\n", i, *(quickNums + i));
    }

    printf("\n");
    clock_t t0 = clock();
    bubbleSort(bubbleNums, number);
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    printf("Time to sort bubblesort of %i elements: %d milliseconds\n", number, (t1 - t0));

    clock_t t2 = clock();
    insertSort(insertNums, number);
    clock_t t3 = clock();
    printf("Time to sort insertSort of %i elements: %d milliseconds\n", number, (t3 - t2));

    clock_t t4 = clock();
    quicksort(quickNums, 0, number - 1);
    clock_t t5 = clock();
    printf("Time to sort quicksort of %i elements: %d milliseconds\n", number, (t5 - t4));

        //printf("Bubble\n");
        //printArray(bubbleNums, number);
        //printf("Insert\n");
        //printArray(insertNums, number);
        //printf("Quick\n");
        //printArray(quickNums, number);

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(...) doesn't include constant multipliers or lower order terms. So if the time for one method is 2 x n^2, and another 6 x n^2 + 12 x n + 18, they are both considered to be O(n^2), even though one is more than 3 times as fast as the other.

The O(...) just gives you a first order approximation of how the time for a particular algorithm relates to n.

For the other question, insertion sort is faster because it rotates portions of an array as needed, while bubble sort only swaps pairs.

Comment: ..... I forgot all about constant multipliers. Been so long since I've done O notation I forgot all about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your BubbleSort isn't stopping when the list is sorted. You should track the number of changes per pass. If there aren't any changes, the list is sorted. Right now you're forcing it to always have the worst performance possible.

```
for (x; x < size; x++){
    int changes = 0;
    for (y = 0; y < size - 1; y++){
        if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1]){
            int temp = arr[y + 1];
            arr[y + 1] = arr[y];
            arr[y] = temp;
            changes++;
        }
    }
    if (changes == 0) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the algorithm for the modified bubble sort. It's a valid version of it and a better one at that. Even when I run it with this version with 10000 elements bubble sort takes 612 milliseconds while insert takes 119. I was given a suggestion by a friend that it might have something to do with branching, not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic complexity tells you about how performance *scales* with problem size.  It does not tell you anything about how alternative algorithms for the same task perform relative to one another for the same problem.

Insertion sort turns out to be among the fastest of the O(n<sup>2</sup>) sorting algorithms.  Although it scales the same way as bubble sort, insertion sort tends to perform perform far fewer comparisons and swaps.  How many fewer depends on implementation details and input.